Netsuite AES Encryption incorrect key/iv sizes
So I am recieving a file from Orcales NetSuite that has been encrypted via NetSuite with AES-256-CBC encryption.  However, upon trying to decrypt it with the given key/iv which have verified is what they do have in their NetSuite key file, I noticed both the key and iv are 32 bytes long, which is incorrect.  For AES-256 the IV should be 16 bytes long.  I assumed maybe I needed to decode these strings so I ran it through javascript's node forge library via
forge.util.decode64(iv)
but its the same value coming in, 32 bytes.
Does anyone have experience with NetSuite encryption that could tell me maybe what's going on?  I cannot find any documentation on this at all.
This is an example of a key file I'm getting from NetSuite (not real values obviously):
{"key":"ZC9TZW5iQzQzRGlJOG0yZ3MzQ2NHR3hjOXQwRjBxcG8=","iv":"MTI2NWMwZDU4ZTU4ODZkYjE3MjNhYjJhMzc0M2IzZjk="}

If iv is Base64 decoded, the result can be UTF-8 decoded, s. CyberChef: 1265c0d58e5886db1723ab2a3743b3f9. This can be interpreted as hex encoding of a 16 bytes value. Try this as IV.

It looks like the IV is actually encoded into hex, then into Base64.
This accounts for the doubling in length, as it goes from 8-bit characters to 4-bit in hex.
Decoding the Base64 value to binary data results in this:
0000: 31 32 36 35 63 30 64 35
0010: 38 65 35 38 38 36 64 62
0020: 31 37 32 33 61 62 32 61
0030: 33 37 34 33 62 33 66 39

Looking at this for long enough, you eventually notice that it has low entropy, all of the bytes have the highest bit cleared, and they all start with 3 or 6 (hexadecimal).
If you decode the Base64 and also interpret the data as a hexadecimal string, you get this:
0000: 12 65 c0 d5 8e 58 86 db
0010: 17 23 ab 2a 37 43 b3 f9

...which is precisely 16 bytes long.
This doc page for CipherPayload may have the answer (though I may be interpreting it wrong), where it says:

Note: This property is encoded in encode.Encoding.HEX regardless of the options.inputEncoding parameter value in the cipher.final method.

Edit: Additionally, the key is encoded in a similar fashion, but it replaces the hex encoding with another round of Base64. This is the most likely case, but the first pass results in 32 bytes (AES-256) and the second 24 (AES-192). The official documentation is surprisingly sparse, but it may be due to requesting Base64 encoding when encoding the key. The question does mention AES-256, but it may be different (especially due to the sparse documentation).
In general, messages seem to be encoded according to their settings, and then encoded once again with Base64.
/Edit
Credit to this comment for the idea.

That might work, but I'm not sure as I assume the key would need to go through the same processing via atob(key) and then to hex, which results in a key length of 15 (should be 32).  I don't know why NetSuite's documentation is so bad for this :/

About the key, decoding the base64 results in more base64, decoding to a 192-bit key. I'll look for some documentation, but you could ask another question about the key (or change this one to include it).
